# How to make a MS Acess Report where you have one page per record?

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

I cannot figure this out for the life of me.

I want a report object where each page (no matter how big, small, etc) corresponds to one record in the underlying source query (each record corresponds to a Client along with some financial data).

I've tried grouping by Client, inserting page breaks, trying to integrate forms, etc. Nothing. Everything just combines together into one giant list -- there's no separation per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the Group Header and view Properties (F4).  It should be named something like GroupHeader0.  For the *Force New Page* attribute, select Before Section, After Section, or Before & After Section.

The hardest part of this for me was finding the correct item to click that has the Force New Page attribute -- it isn't the field itself, but the Section (which is named "GroupHeaderX" by default).